# Confused about python decimal library

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, precision

I am doing quantitative analysis on Python, comparing results with another colleague we found these typical float discrepancies on the 17th decimal place or so due to different operation order.

Looking for a solution I found the decimal library, read the docs and ran some examples

```py
# This is using fixed point arithmetic, resulting on what we would expect
Decimal('0.1') + Decimal('0.2') == Decimal('0.3')

# This is using floating point arithmetic, and thus will never reach 
# the exact number using base 2, the famous 0.30000000000000004
x = 0.1 + 0.2

# But what is this doing? It outputs 0.3000000000000000166533453694, which 
# suggests a floating point usage, but different error
x = Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.2)
```

So at this point I am really confused, why is this error different from the vanilla python float, and if I want to use this library alongside Pandas, do I have to cast to str every single operand?

Comment: Try `Context(prec=2).create_decimal_from_float(0.2)`. I took it from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Decimal(0.1)` you don't get exactly 0.1, the constant 0.1 that you fed to `Decimal` is already off due to the usual floating point inaccuracies - see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987)  It's an exact representation of an inexact number.  When you use `Decimal('0.1')` you *do* get an exact 0.1, because the conversion from string is performed by `Decimal` itself.

The conversion from `float` to `str` applies a tiny bit of rounding, it may fix things or it may not.

Comment: So unless Decimal objects are initialized with hardcoded strings there is no way to avoid innaccuracies 

Something like

```python 
Decimal(str(df["amount"][0])) 
```

Which was a float64 in origin is already flawed, did I get it right?

Comment: @Dakolas yes you have it right.  To see that `float64` value with more precision, try printing `f'{df["amount"][0]:0.60}'`.